# HAVING MAX(COUNT(*)) not working

Tags: sql, count, max

I have the following code:

```
SELECT  e.Student_ID, s.Name, s.Surname, Result_IS, COUNT(*) 
FROM Students s 
LEFT JOIN Exams e
  ON e.Student_ID=s.Student_ID
WHERE Result_IS='Negative'
GROUP BY e.Student_ID, s.Name, s.Surname, Result_IS
HAVING COUNT(*)=
(
  SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) FROM Exams
  WHERE Student_ID=e.Student_ID
    AND Result_IS='Negative'
  GROUP BY e.Student_ID, s.Name, s.Surname, Result_IS
)
```

I'm having problem with the `HAVING COUNT(*)` which should select the row where the `COUNT(*)` gave the biggest result, but instead it just giving me the output of the first select, which is the following:

[image: The output]

I've been trying all sort of things but nothing works to select the row, where count is the maximum.

Just give me a hint please in which direction should I move from here, and what is wrong with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just order by count(*) desc and select top 1?

```
SELECT top 1  e.Student_ID, s.Name, s.Surname, Result_IS, COUNT(*) FROM Students s LEFT JOIN Exams e
ON e.Student_ID=s.Student_ID
WHERE Result_IS='Negative'
GROUP BY e.Student_ID, s.Name, s.Surname, Result_IS
order by count(*) desc
```

I think this is the syntax for Oracle

```
  Select * FROM 
    (
            SELECT e.Student_ID, s.Name, s.Surname, Result_IS, COUNT(*) FROM Students s LEFT JOIN Exams e
            ON e.Student_ID=s.Student_ID
            WHERE Result_IS='Negative'
            GROUP BY e.Student_ID, s.Name, s.Surname, Result_IS
            order by count(*) desc
) 
    Where rownum=1
```

Comment: Thank you, but I knew this method already and I didn't wanted to do it this way. By the way, in the meantime I figured out how to do it. But thanks anyway :)

Comment: You should post your answer here for the community.

Comment: PL/SQL is Oracle's procedural language.  You probably meant to say "Oracle SQL".  And for Oracle, you have to be careful about mixing `rownum` and `order by` in the same query, because the `rownum` filter gets applied *before* the `order by`, so the results will be incorrect.  Instead, you would want something like: `select * from (subquery-with-order-by) where rownum = 1`.

Answer (score 1):

Do

```
HAVING COUNT(*)=
(
SELECT MAX(COUNT(*)) FROM Exams
WHERE Student_ID=e.Student_ID
AND Result_IS='Negative'
GROUP BY e.Student_ID, s.Name, s.Surname, Result_IS
)
```

query on the joined table. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, I found out how to do it, the solution is the following:

```
SELECT  e.Student_ID, s.Name, s.Surname, Result_IS, COUNT(*) FROM Students s LEFT JOIN Exams e
ON e.Student_ID=s.Student_ID
WHERE Result_IS='Negative'
GROUP BY e.Student_ID, s.Name, s.Surname, Result_IS
HAVING COUNT(*)=
(
SELECT MAX(count) from
(
SELECT count(*) as count FROM Exams
WHERE Result_Is='Negative'
GROUP BY Student_ID
) 
)
```